# How do I map two entities in ColdFusion ORM that are in different schemas?

Tags: oracle, orm, coldfusion, mapping, coldfusion-9

I have two tables that exist in the same **Oracle** database system but different schemas, which I've mapped like this:

```
ABC.Store:
component schema="ABC" table="Stores"
{
    property name="Id" fieldtype="id" generator="sequence" sequence="store_id_seq";
    property name="Products" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="Product";
}

DEF.Product:
component schema="DEF" table="Products"
{
    property name="Id" fieldtype="id" generator="sequence" sequence="product_id_seq";
}
```

I set my application's default datasource as `this.datasource = "ABC"` in **application.cfc**.

The problem I'm running into here is whenever I try to save a `Product`. ColdFusion spits out an error that says the sequence cannot be found for the `Id` property on `Product`. This is because the `product_id_seq` sequence is in the DEF schema, but ColdFusion is trying to find it in the ABC schema, even though I set the schema on the `Product` as DEF.

If I set the `datasource` attribute on `Product` to `DEF`, I then get an error that says the `Products` property on `Store` is unmapped. This is because, as the ColdFusion documentation states:

> "Since a Hibernate configuration uses a single data source, all related CFCs (using ORM relationships) must have the same data source."

**My question then is**, how do I map the two tables in two different schemas, using a sequence as an ID generator?

I've been able to get it to work if I specify the schema for the sequence:

```
property name="Id" fieldtype="id" generator="sequence" sequence="def.product_id_seq";
```

But this is hard-coded and I'd like it to be dynamic and pull the schema name from a configuration bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **only** way I've been able to get this to work seamlessly was to:

1. Create a single user in database, in this case MySQL, that had access to the desired schemas.
2. Setup and configure a single datasource in CFIDE that utilizes the newly created user for authentication.
3. Set the `datasource` attribute in all desired persistent objects to the newly created datasource.
4. Set the `schema` attribute in all desired persistent objects to reference the correct schema, or database. *(the two are synonymous in ColdFusion ORM)*

**Note:** Be sure to use full component path when referencing CFCs in your COM.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too on MySQL, but only when I used the "catalog" attribute for the other database, rather than "schema".